# How do i dynamically cast a child class from its parent class?

Tags: c#, winforms

Here is what i am trying to do. I have a class called in **ParentForm** its essentialy a **Form** class with 2 things added.

Then everyother **Form** i make i inherit **ParentForm** to it so i have like

```
class f1: ParentForm
class f2: ParentForm
class f3: ParentForm
etc...
```

Now lets say that i have a button in **f1** and **f2** both open the **f3** form and the **f3** form constructor looks like this:

```
public f3(ParentForm parent)
```

I use this to pass variables back to the original form(in this case either **f1** or **f2**), to add data to Lists there or whatever else.

Now here comes my problem i have been doing things like this for now:

```
if (parent.GetType() == typeof(f1))
    {
        ((f1)parent).list.Add("a");
    }
    else if (parent.GetType() == typeof(f2))
    {
        ((f2)parent).list.Add("a");
    }
```

So i create a check for every parent, how can i do this dynamicly? Something like

```
((parent.GetType())parent).list.Add("a");
```

But ofcourse this doesnt work, anybody got a solution?

Comment: can't you move the list to the ParentForm ?

Comment: If you can't move such list in the parent form (for example because of layout) just expose a List abstract property of type ListBox. f1 will implement it to return right control (same will do f2). f3 will access them through inherited abstract property.

Comment: No some forms dont use lists like lets say i have 6 difrents froms 3 use lists 2 use treeview and one uses juts a textbox. Is it immposible to do what i am trying to do? Dynamicly cast?

Comment: Side comment, don't use *Parent* word, *BaseForm* would be more appropriate name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure that this is the best solution, but here how I would do this:

```
abstract class ParentForm{
    ...
    public abstract void Update<T>(T updateValue)
}

public class f1 : ParentForm{
    ...
    private List<string> list;
    public override void Update(string value){
    list.Add(value);
}
}

public class f2 : ParentForm{
    ....
    private List<int> list;
public override void Update(int val){
 ...
}
}
```

and so on

Answer (score 1):

There are two options:

1. `ParentForm` contains the definition for the list:

   ```
   public List<string> TheList { get;private set;}
   ```
2. Each form implements the same `interface` with a `abstract` implementation:

   ```
   public abstract class ParentForm : IFormWithList
   {
       public abstract List<string> TheList { get; }
   }
   ```

   Where `IFormWithList` is:

   ```
   List<string> TheList { get; }
   ```

   Then you should declare it in each deriving class:

   ```
   public class f1 : ParentForm
   {
       public override List<string> TheList { get { return this.list; } }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comment, You can define following `Interface`s:

```
IMyForm
{
}
IFormWithList:IMyForm
{
    ListBox ListBox { get; set; }
}
IFormWithTreeView:IMyForm
{
    TreeView TreeView { get; set; }
}
```

Your forms inherit from appropriate `Interface`:

```
 class f1: IWithListForm
 class f2: IWithListForm
 class f3: IWithListForm
```

Now, you can inject `IMyForm` instead `ParentForm`:

```
 public f3(IMyForm parent)
```

Answer (score 0):

You Actually can also achieve the same goal using a `virual` method or property. 
If you declare your Add method, Or Property virtual, their respective method or property is called automatically. 
meaning if you have :

```
 class Parent
    {
        public virtual void Add(string msg)
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Parent got msg");
        }
    }

    class child1:Parent
    {
        public override void Add(string msg)
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Child 1 Got Msg");
        }
    }

    class child2 : Parent
    {
        public override void Add(string msg)
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Child 2 Got Msg");
        }

    }
```

Simply using them like :

```
  Parent p;
  ...
  p = new child1();
  p.Add("Test"); // will call child1's add method
  p = new child2();
  p.Add("Test"); // will call child2's add method
```